# T-SQL splitting column on a delimiter

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a column with three groups data delimited by a forward slash, like so

```
AB/1234/10
```

The column is always formatted the same in every row, with 2 characters, a slash, some number of characters, a slash, and then 2 more characters. I need to split this one column into three. So the above example becomes

```
Column1 Column2 Column3
AB      1234    10
```

I'm not quite sure how to go about this. I've been using `SELECT SUBSTRING` but that isn't quite giving me what I need.

```
select SUBSTRING(MyColumn, 1, CHARINDEX('/', MyColumn, 1)-1) 
FROM MyTable
```

Will return `AB`, and that's great. But I can't wrap my mind around how to grab the middle and the end sections. I thought that

```
select SUBSTRING(MyColumn, 4, CHARINDEX('/', MyColumn, 4)) 
FROM MyTable
```

Would work in grabbing the middle, but it returns `1234/10`

I hope my question is clear and I would appreciate any advice pointing me in the right direction, Thank you.

Comment: Ideally part of this exercise should be to permanently separate this data. Storing multiple elements like this violates 1NF and is nothing short of painful to work with.

Comment: If you use a splitter like in the proposed duplicate you should avoid the accepted answer as it is a terrible way to split string. Instead scroll down to Aaron Bertrand's answer. It is much better for performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work with fixed offsets, since you defined that the string always starts with two, and ends with two characters.

Here is a full working example:

```
DECLARE @tmp TABLE (
  Merged nvarchar(max)
)

INSERT INTO @tmp SELECT N'AB/1234/10'
INSERT INTO @tmp SELECT N'AB/ANYNUMBEROF-CHARACTERS/10'

SELECT
  LEFT(Merged,2) AS Column1,
  SUBSTRING(Merged,4,LEN(Merged)-6) AS Column2,
  RIGHT(Merged,2) AS Column3
FROM @tmp
```

We subtract the length of the string minus a constant (6 = two chars left, two chars right, two slashes) to extract the variable-length part from the middle.

Result:

```
Column1 Column2                Column3
AB      1234                   10
AB      ANYNUMBEROF-CHARACTERS 10
```

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to use `PARSENAME`:

```
SELECT PARSENAME(REPLACE('AB/1234/10','/','.'), 3) Col1,
       PARSENAME(REPLACE('AB/1234/10','/','.'), 2) Col2,
       PARSENAME(REPLACE('AB/1234/10','/','.'), 1) Col3
```

This will replace the `/` with `.`, and pull out each section of the string with `PARSENAME`.

The benefit is that it will work with any length of characters in any position.  The limits is that `PARSENAME` only handles up to 4 positions (in this case you are using 3), and will fail if periods `.` exist in the string already.

Comment: I like this trick a lot but it fails miserably if any of the source strings contains a dot.

Comment: An easy way to deal with a period is to add a replace first to swap out a . with something like ^. You would have to swap it back of course which kind of starts to get a bit over the top for this simple one.

Comment: Unfortunately any or all of the strings in my case can contain a `.` so while this answer is good, its not applicable in my case. Thanks anyway however.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.  This should work with any number of characters.

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(100) = 'AB/1234/10'

SELECT LEFT(@str, CHARINDEX('/', @str) - 1) AS Column1
    , SUBSTRING(@str, CHARINDEX('/', @str) + 1, CHARINDEX('/', SUBSTRING(@str, CHARINDEX('/', @str) + 1, LEN(@str))) - 1) AS Column2
    , RIGHT(@str, CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(@str)) - 1) AS Column3
```

Comment: If I could mark multiple answers as correct I would also mark this one, its essentially the same kind of answer that I marked at correct, but I really appreciate the robustness of it. It's much more applicable in a general use. Thank you.